# AJAX Calls from one subdomain to other

Tags: ajax, subdomain

I want to call AJAX Request from one subdomain to other.

Say I want to request http://**subdomain2**.site.com/ajax/handler.ashx from a ASPX page on other subdomain http://**subdomain1**.site.com/Default.aspx

Any IDEA how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript, you can set `document.domain` to a suffix of the domain, so

```
 document.domain='example.com'
```

However, I have not tested this.

Answer (score 0):

have you taken a look at [JSONP](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Ajax#Cross-Domain_getJSON_.28using_JSONP.29)?